# Aurelia: How to set property on view model during activate?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

Disclaimer: I'm VERY new to Aurelia so this might be an obvious question.

I'm having a javascript scope issue while trying to set a property in an Aurelia view model. In the following code, when my API call completes and I enter the promise in the activate method 'this' is undefined. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class ListTasks{

    constructor(httpClient) {
        this.http = httpClient; 
        this.tasks = [];
    }

    activate() {
        this.http.get('api/task').then(function(result){
            // 'this' is undefined in the scope of this function
            this.tasks = result.content;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my issue was coming from a scoping issue that ES2015 arrow functions solve. By using an typical anonymous function declaration, the scope of 'this' was changed. Replacing the anonymous function with an arrow function handles the scope properly:

```js
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class ListTasks{

    constructor(httpClient) {
        this.http = httpClient; 
        this.tasks = [];
    }

    activate() {
        this.http.get('api/task').then(result => {
            // 'this' is undefined in the scope of this function
            this.tasks = result.content;
        });
    }
}
```